# Big-O notation for complex loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I can not guess the Big-O notation for this loops.

```
for (int j = 2; j < N; j++) {
    for (int k = 2*j; k <= N; k += j) {
        nums[k] = false;
    }
}
```

How to calculate the algorithm complexity for this loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick for this is Calculus to replace a sum by an integral that we understand.

```
for y from 2 to N:
    do roughly N/j things
```

So we have a sum of:

```
N/2 + N/3 + N/4 + ... + N/N
    = N (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/N)
```

And that sum can be approximated with the integral from `1` to `N` of `1/x`.  Whose integral is `log(x)`.  So, modulo errors, it requires `O(N log(N))` steps.

I waved my hands vigorously.  But I assure you that the rigorous details can be filled in, and "replace sum by approximate integral" has a `O(1)` error.

Comment: Might be good to mention harmonic numbers here in the context of that integral?

Comment: @templatetypedef I was trying to keep it simple. :-)

Comment: Very reasonable. :-) I figure that harmonic numbers are one of those math-y things that are good to know about in computing since they show up elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 2; j < N; j++) {  ==> it runs for "N-2" times
  for (int k = 2*j; k <= N; k += j) {
      nums[k] = false;
  }
}

for inner loop, let 'h' be no. of times inner loop has been called

   if j = 2 ==> values of k are 4,6,8,12,.....,2h ==> 2(2),3(2),....,h(2)
      j = 3 ==> values of k are 6,9,12,15,.....,3h ==> 3(2),3(3),....,h(3)
      :
      :
      j = N-1 ==> values of k are 2(N-1),3(N-1),4(N-1).......h(N-1)
 
here, inner loop stops when value of k > N

      => last time loop called will be for k < N or k = N
      => h(N-1) = N
      => h = N/N-1 => no of times inner loop is called

T(N) = (N-2) * (N/N-1) = O(N^2);
```