# Time complexity of nested loops involving addition

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

```
for (let j = 2; j < N; j++) {  = n times
    for (let k = 2*j; k <= N; k += j) {
        do_sth;
    }
}
```

How can we find the time complexity of the function

for j =2  k = 4,6,8... for j = N-1   k = 2N-2, 3N-3...,m

we look for k>N k=N  m=N

any guidance?

Comment: Are you from the same algorithms class as this guy? [Big-O notation for complex loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886379/big-o-notation-for-complex-loop)

Comment: @Berthur I'm not that guy but could not get the idea of N/j like the first guy did

Comment: The trick is counting the number of times the inner loop will run, as a function of j. You might find these relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: I think it would be exactly true if it was like for(k=j ;k<=N;k+=j;), since it is not like that we can only say it is roughly. How can we manage to do it with exact accuracy

Comment: Or I think we can do it like ceil(N/j-2)

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop is run at some number of iterations that is a divisor of N

Since the outer loop runs N times, and the inner loop iterates at some factor N/x, the total complexity of the two loops is N * N/X = N^2/X which is O(N^2)